# How to make a div not propagate it's own width

Tags: css

I want a setup like this:

```
.---------------.
| .-----------. |
| |  title    | |
| '-----------' |
| .----. .----. |
| | A  | | B  | |
| '----' '----' |
'---------------'
```

where `title` doesn't push its own width but adapts to the width dictated by `A` and `B`.

I currently have

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="title">this text needs to break, too long</div>
    <div class="cell"> I am AAAA    </div>
    <div class="cell"> I am BBBB    </div>
</div>

<style>
 .row  {margin: 30px; display: inline-block;}
 .cell {margin: 10px; display: inline-block;}
 .title {overflow: auto; clear:both}
</style>
```

But `title` does not break here.

Comment: width of A and B will be dynamic ? or defined with % or values ?

Comment: Use flexbox. It is built for this problem.

Comment: @TemaniAfif width of A and B will be defined by their content

Comment: @Shammoo show us a solution with flex :) i don't see how it can be done with flex, so i will be happy to see it !

Comment: Hm, i can't see solution without using of javascript...

Comment: @sinisake yes i think not possible with pure CSS. but i see that Shammoo got upvoted so am waiting to see a flex solution :)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Okay, but the code won't be very clean.

Comment: @TemaniAfif . I made the code cleaner than I thought I would. Please accept if this is an appropriate solution for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Flex 0 the inner div to stop it from growing.

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.size-constrain {
  flex: 0;
}

.r { background-color: red }
.b { background-color: blue }
.y { background-color: yellow }
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="size-constrain">
        <div class="r">
            Part A
        </div>
        <div class="outer">
            <div class="b" style="width: 100px;">Part B</div>
            <div class="y" style="width: 100px;">Part C</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but, remove fixed widths, add more text, and....https://jsfiddle.net/eqrgnsa5/

Comment: it's not my question :) and you didn't read it i think ... first you changed the whole html structure and then as @sinisake said. So this solution doesn't meet any of the requirement

Comment: Just add `.title {overflow: auto; clear: both; white-space: nowrap;}` and add that class to the div wrapping Part A if that's what you want... I gave you the structure you need to follow, I shouldn't have to write the entire program for you... I gave you a general POC for the problem at large.

Comment: again it's not my question :)

Comment: and i know how to do it with javascript ... and the purpose of this site is to give a full solution, not 10% of the easy part of the solution, as what you did is common, you added nothing .